# Firebase functions rewrites/redirects with custom subdomain

Tags: node.js, redirect, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am setting up a Firebase application (API) with a custom subdomain (api.usa.company.com). I have several firebase functions each for different types of apis.

For example Housing, Rentals, Services.

I am looking to achieve the following:

- Calls made to api.usa.company.com/housing should redirect/rewrite to Housing function.
- Calls made to api.usa.company.com/rentals should
  redirect/rewrite to Rentals function and similar for other 10-15
  functions.

My firebase.json is as follows:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/:functionName/**",
        "function": ":functionName"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "https://company.com",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

I want to make my life easier by doing dynamic redirects, instead of me typing rewrites for every function I created and will create in function.

I have tried using the above firebase.json, which resulted in error. I am sure I am missing a logic somewhere, which I couldn't figure out. Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Firebase Hosting doesn't support placeholders using colons.  Have you seen the [documentation for rewrite configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) that explains how to do this? There is a lot written (including examples) about using regular expressions to match path segments.